# Unable to find the cache key in memcache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached, rabl

I am using gem `rabl` for building my api response (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

In my controller, I have given like this

```
@cache_key = "rabl/spree/api/home/v2/index-en"
```

and in my index.rabl file, I gave,

```
cache @cache_key, expires_in: 15.minutes
```

I am using memcache for caching using the client Dalli and have deployed the application in heroku. Everything is working as expected. But when I am trying

```
Rails.cache.fetch('rabl/spree/api/home/v2/index-en')
```

I am not able to see any value. Why is it like this ? Does rabl append any value to cache key ?

Comment: "in my rabl file" - not familiar with this gem - where is this located? Is it evaluated each time the controller action runs? Otherwise `@cache_key` may be nil ... it's worth checking this.

Comment: This is the gem 'rabl'. And by in my rabl file, i meant my view file(index.rabl). Every time the controller action runs, this value is instantiated.

Comment: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/blob/b876c8a86a92f49a52163c061c185e6764be57ce/lib/rabl/engine.rb#L54

Comment: According to this https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/blob/b876c8a86a92f49a52163c061c185e6764be57ce/lib/rabl/engine.rb#L213, If we set `cache "rabl/spree/api/home/v2/index-en"
` then this would be my key. But I am not able to get this key from memcache.

Comment: Does this help? [https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Caching-in-RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Caching-in-RABL)